# Grammatical structure of the sentence "There is no dinosaur skin left to study."

Tags: past-participles, complements, existentials

I am trying to figure out the grammatical structure of the following sentence:

> There is no dinosaur skin left to study.

This is what I have:

```
There is -> (what?) -> no skin -> (which/what?) -> left -> (for what?) -> (to study).
```

What is the word *left* (in a grammatical sense)? It's definitely not acting as a verb here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > There is no dinosaur skin left to study

The types of word in the sentence are:

- **there**, pronoun
- **is** auxiliary verb
- **no** determiner *
- **dinosaur** noun
- **skin** noun,
- **left** adjective
- **to** [very contentious word] 'subordinator'
- **study** verb, infinitive

[*Determiners are words like: *a, the, this, that, my, your, no, one, two*.]

This sentence is an example of an existential construction.

The subject of the sentence is [*there*], the predicate is [*is no dinosaur skin left to study*]. The predicate consists of the auxiliary verb [*is*] and two complements, which are the noun phrase [*no dinosaur skin to study*] and the adjective [*left*]. Further below I will show what has happened to this noun phrase and why it has broken into two sections.

The noun phrase can be represented like this:

- [[no][dinosaur skin to study]]

It has an external modifier, the determiner [*no*], and an 'inner noun phrase', sometimes called a *nominal*: [*dinosaur skin to study*]. The nominal, and indeed the whole noun phrase is headed by the noun [*skin*]. [*Skin*] is being premodified by  another noun [*dinosaur*], giving us the compound noun [*dinosaur skin*]. The noun has a post-head modifier, the infinitival clause [*to study*]. Depending on which grammar you read, this could have different structures. In CaGEL, the analysis would be that the head of the clause is the verb [*study*]. This is marked by the subordinator [*to*].

In this sentence we see something called '*extraposition from noun phrase movement*. Sometimes, if a noun phrase is very 'heavy', if it is very long, we can move part of it to the end of the sentence. We could build the sentence like this:

- There is no dinosaur skin to study left.

But this is a little bit difficult to understand, because we have to wait a long time to hear the second complement *left*. We can move that section *to study* 'out of the noun phrase and put it at the end of the sentence. (*Extra* in extraposition means '*out*; *position* means something like *putting*). This gives us the Original Poster's example:

- There is no dinosaur skin left to study.

The CaGEL is the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston & Pullum, Cambridge University Press, 2002.

Hope this is helpful!

[[**Analysis Note**: The grammatical structure of this sentence might be a little ambiguous. This is an existential construction. For the purposes of this analysis I have taken the non-existential version of this sentence to be: [*No dinosaur skin to study was left*]. The following alternative is not felicitous: [* *No dinosaur skin left was to study*] (wrong). This last fact accounts for the extraposition analysis. However, there is always: [*No dinosaur skin was left to study*]. The most natural reading of this sentence, does not have the same meaning as the existential counterpart.]]

Comment: Why don't we say "*There's no left food"?

Comment: Wow! That's made an impression on me!

Comment: How about "There's no real difference"?

Comment: @TRomano What about it? '*Is*' only has one complement there, the noun phrase '*no real difference*'. There's nothing to move any of the noun phrase past ... :) Does that make sense?

Comment: @TRomano Sorry just realised this :-/ EDIT: because the 'nominal', ***food***, is only one word long! The noun phrase is of course two words: *no food*. With extraposition from noun phrase movement, the main section of the noun phrase which includes the head noun stays in the normal position - the rest of it moves to the end of the senetence. But there is no rest of the noun phrase to move with the single word food! :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding. What *prevents* "left" from being placed before the noun "food", as "real" is placed before the noun "difference"?  Are "left" and "real" adjectival in different ways?

Comment: @TRomano I right. I wondered if that was going to come up, i was waiting for F.E. for that one! If *left* is an adjective, then it's not able to be used attributively, a bit like the adjective *alive* ... (continued)

Comment: @TRomano ... There is of course an argument that *left* is a verb. It would pass some of the tests for verb-hood in comparison to adjective-hood. The reason I take it to be an adjective and not a verb is that there seems to be a distinction between the two meanings of *one cup was left yesterday afternoon* in the same way that there is a distinction between the verb and adjective readings of *two clocks were broken yesterday afternoon* (someone left one or broke one yesterday afternoon, versus they were in the state of being broken/remaining yesterday afternoon). But not everyone'll agree!

Comment: @TRomano The other complicating factor here is that *left* is not modifying dinosaur skin in the OP's example. It is a complement of the verb *BE*. In 'there were three plates left' it looks like it's postmodifying 'plates', but it isn't.

Comment: *EDIT NOTE: there will be a complete rewrite of this post later this afternoon.* <-- Wot?

Comment: Er, where be that promised "afternoon" rewrite?

Comment: I've been in hospital :( long story. Will get onto it later this eve ...

Answer (score 3):

The past participle of *leave* - *left* - can be used in a special way, to mean 'remaining', 'not used, 'still there'.

Michael Swan (2005.320), *Practical English Usage.*

Comment: Could you give a link to what grammatical structure it is?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your particular concern, you are definitely precise, the word **left** doesn’t function as a verb.

In your context **left** functions as an [adjective](http://faculty.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/partadj.html). It modifies (describes) the noun skin.

Comment: Then what is really confusing, is word order for that particular case: *left to study* follows noun, instead of preceding it.

Comment: Is there a name for grammatical construction: adjective derived from verb?

Comment: Usually adjectives are placed before the nouns they modify, yet there are exceptions: [see postpositive adjectives](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/postpos.htm)